# How do I block ALL callers from leaving voicemail?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, voicemail, motorola-moto-g5

My work is with liars who like to lie about leaving messages. As a result, I have incorporated notice into my contract that they cannot leave me a voicemail, send text messages, or send emails (which are a security risk in my profession).

I have had people stand right in front of me and look me straight in the eye and say the left me a voicemail message, even though I haven't had voicemail since 1990s.

Here is the problem:

I recently purchased a new unlocked Moto G5 Plus from Motorola; and service through Republic Wireless. Republic set it up so that I had to run an update in order for the service to be turned on. This update forced me to activate voicemail in order to complete the update. Now they tell me they can't shut off voice mail, too bad, so sad.

I don't have time to play games with liars who say they've left me a voicemail. It's too time consuming to mess with this.

I would like it to say I do not accept voicemail, but I will return missed calls listed on caller ID. That would be a bonus.

I'm not sure if it's Nougat 7.0 or 7.1. I tried to find it in the phone, but I guess I'm not that smart.

**This is what Republic Wireless has to say about the matter.**

**"I see you are looking for a way to disable the voicemail feature on your Moto G5+ phone and have come to a sticking point with the fact that this is not a feature that Republic Wireless offers. I'm sorry to hear the request is not one we can complete for you at this time but it appears you are looking for anyway to shut voicemail off.  There are two workaround solutions i have found that will get your desired results. The first is to simply fill your voicemail inbox up. To do this, we recommend you call your Republic number 5-7 times and play music for 5-7 minutes into the voicemail each time. Once full all callers will hear is a message that states your voicemail box is full and the caller will not be able to leave a message.  The other option is to use the voicemail forwarding option within the Republic App on your phone. You can forward your number to an unanswered line where the caller again will not be able to leave a message. Our best recommendation in this situation is to obtain a free number from GoogleVoice to forward to.  I hope these alternative solutions will have the desired result for you and if you have any questions in completing either of them please let us know."**

It appears they are telling me my options are 1. to waste a huge amount of storage space to fill up the voicemail box, or, 2. to use a google program that has a lot of poor reviews on CNET, and doesn't seem to specifically address my issue.

Please, someone tell me how to block all callers from leaving voicemail, and if possible, to say No leaving voicemail, but I will return missed calls.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't you just go in the dialer app and turn off the call forwarding? Go to the dialer/Phone app, go to the go to the Settings, select Call Settings, Call Forwarding, and change When Busy, When Unanswered, and When unreachable to Off? Works with most phones (menu may vary slightly) and most carriers, although since RW is primarily a "VoIP" WiFi carrier they may be in complete control of the forwarding. Sounds like if this is a serious issue, you may want to switch carriers to something more traditional.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a VoIP provider**

Like Google voice/Grass Hopper that allows you to either turn off voice mail or get it transcribed and emailed to you.

Handing out your VoIP number you can have people call that and forward to your phone and if you don't pick up you can turn off voicemail or probably better get it transcribed and sent to you.

Comment: The OP already mentioned they don't want to use Google Voice.

Comment: @Iszi, Yup, but since voicemail is handled on the carrier network and the carrier apparently won't turn it off, the only way to not go to voicemail is to go to forward the call to a VoIP provider and terminate the call there. Besides, I did list an alternative: Grass Hopper :) And unless he wants to install a asterisk box and handle his own routing and forwarding this is probably the way to go.